# How to handle the calculation of piecewise functions?

Tags: functions

Given piecewise function f [x]:

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1/x, x < 0}, {x^2, x >= 0}}]
```

Another function g [x]:

```
g[x_] = x + 1
```

Want to calculate `g[f[x]]`

get the result is:

[image]

How can I obtain the correct answer as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
g[f[x]] //  PiecewiseExpand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> How to make the definition field display as: x>=0?

I do  not know offhand without writing special code to post-process it. But these are really the same.   i.e. `True` in this case is the same as `x>=0`, because `True` means for all other possible values of `x`, which is `x>=0`.

[image]

So Mathematically they are the same. If you want `x>=0` to show there instead of `True` just for display purposes, I think special code might be needed to do this. I could not see an option in `PiecewiseExpand` to change this when I just looked. May be someone will have an idea how to do this easily.

Comment: The definition field corresponding to 1+x ^ 2 in the obtained results is true. How to make the definition field display as: x>=0?

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1/x, x < 0}, {x^2, x >= 0}}];

g[x_] = x + 1;
```

As shown by Nasser,

```
h[x_] = g[f[x]] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

Post-processing,

```
h2[x_] = ReplacePart[
  h[x], {1 -> Append[h[x][[1]], {h[x][[2]], Not[h[x][[1, 1, -1]]]}],
   2 -> 0}]
```

[image]